# Обновления поля в таблице

Tags: sql-server, sql

Задача заменить дату окончания действия документа (datee) на 2012-12-12  для записей со статусом 500 (поле status).

Немножко неправильно сформировал вопрос. Имеется скрипт

```
select * 
from polis
join pers on polis.idpers=pers.idpers
join PersStatus on polis.idpers=PersStatus.idpers
where idstatus='52'
and polis.polisdateF is  null
and polis.polistype!=1
and datestatus between '20120101' and '20121107'
```

Затем в том, что он выбрал (список). В этом списке у всех поменять дату (polisdatee)для where idstatus='52'.

```
update polis set polisdatee='20121015' where ???
```

Comment: И что конктерно не получается?

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: как по выборке изменить данные в совсем другой таблице

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас запрос обращается к двум таблицам, то в `UPDATE` надо прописать алиас той таблицы, данные в которой вы собираетесь обновлять.

Пример c обновлением таблицы, присоединенной в джойне:

```
update t2
   set somefield = 'somevalue'
  from table t
       inner join table2 t2
               on t.id = t2.id
 where something = 1
```

Пример понятен, или нужно детальнее объяснять? Если детальнее - приведите пример своего запроса с объяснением того, какое поле в какой таблице находится (из запроса в комментарии к вопросу это непонятно).

Comment: имеются таблицы polis и PersStatus связываю их по idpers отбираю только те что имеют idstatus='52' (idstatus поле в таблице PersStatus). Формируется список. затем по этому списку мне нужно в таблице polis заменить поле polisdatee

Comment: Выложите схему таблиц, так Вам быстрее помогут

Comment: 1 таблица Polis поля idpers, polisdatee
2 таблица PersStatus поля idpers, idstatus

Нужно отобрать записи имеющие idstatus=52 и затем поменять polisdatee для этих записей в другой таблице

Answer (score 1):

По результатам комментов (если всё правильно понял), как-то так:

```
update Polis set polisdatee='20121015' where idpers in (select idpers from PersStatus where idstatus=52)
```